# Open GL, glDrawElements, GL_LINE_LOOP does not connect vertices correctly

Tags: android, opengl-es

When I draw one square with following vertices:

```
private static float[] vertexArray = {
        // vertex
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f            
};
private static short indicesArray[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3,
};
```

result is good it draws loop correctly[image]

but when I draw another parallel square by following

```
 private static float[] vertexArray = {
        // vertex
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, 0.5f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,

};
private static short indicesArray[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 2, 3,

        4, 5, 6,
        4, 6, 7,
};
```

result is this:
[image]
[image]

I don't know why it does that. I think there something that i don't know about how **GL_LINE_LOOP** works. **GL_LINE_STRIPS** give same result too.
How to fix this? I want the squares to be separate.

code is following:

```
  GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_LINE_LOOP, indicesArray.length,GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
```

Thanks in Advance.

sorry for big pictures I hope someone gonna help me to fix it.

Comment: `GL_LINE_LOOP` doesn't know when you expect to start a new primitiv. All the indices in the array form a single line loop, rather than 2 separate objects.

Comment: Yeah .. Seems like I have never told the open GL that I wanted it to draw the lines by triangles. Seems like I have to call the draw for every primitive I want to display. use the last offset variable in the for loop.

Comment: Another possibility is [Primitive Restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart)

Comment: Yeah that clears much. Thank you! .. That was the help I was looking for.

Comment: In your linked wiki it says it does .. Interesting is that you don't need to say anything to GL if you type the max number of the type you're using, it restarts itself, for short it's 65535 and 0xFFFF as i understand.

Comment: It has to be enabled by `glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw multiple [`GL_LINE_LOOP`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives) with a single draw call, then you can use the [Primitive Restart](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart) technology.

The fixed primitiv restart indes has to be 2^N-1, where N is the number of bits of the data type which is used for the indices.
This means *255* for `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, 65535 for `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` and 2147483647 for `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`.

Add the index to the index list, in between the indices which form the separated primitives:

```java
private static short indicesArray[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,

    65535, // restart primitive

    4, 5, 6,
    4, 6, 7,
};
```

Primitive restart with fixed indices has to be enabled:

```java
glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART_FIXED_INDEX);
```

---

In desktop OpenGL it would be possible to choose the restart index by [`glPrimitiveRestartIndex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPrimitiveRestartIndex.xhtml). This has to be enabled by `glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART)`.